# TypeError undefined reading onDeviceChange makes the website crash if opened in testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

My goal here is to navigate with testcafe to my website (dev.remo.co) but for some reason Im getting the following.
[image]

The code is really not relevant. I issued details in the hammerhead repo but I'm not sure if this depends on them
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2859

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce the issue. As a workaround, try using the [Proxyless Mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/experimental-capabilities/proxyless-mode). TestCafe team is actively working on this mode.

```
testcafe chrome tests --experimental-proxyless
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! The proxyless mode doesn't seem to help though.

Comment: Let's continue our discussion in the GitHub [issue you created](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2859).